# JSF2.0 Some facesmessages not sent to redirected page on error handling

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, error-handling, apache-tomee

I'm building a JSF2.0 application on TomEE1.7.3,
and I've created a custom ExceptionHander, and overrided handle() method,
which looks like below:

```
@Override
public void handle() {
    for (Iterator<ExceptionQueuedEvent> it = getUnhandledExceptionQueuedEvents().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        ExceptionQueuedEventContext eventContext = it.next().getContext();
        FacesContext facesContext = eventContext.getContext();
        ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
        Throwable throwable = eventContext.getException();
        if (throwable instanceof ViewExpiredException) {
            facesContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(
                    FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "",
                    "oops, view state error! This FacesMessage is sent to error.xhtml, just as expected."));
        } else {
            facesContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(
                    FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "",
                    "oops, some OTHER error! This FacesMessage is NOT sent to error.xhtml, " + 
                    "I want full stacktrace here, string length is irrelevant to the problem ..."));
        }
        externalContext.getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);
        externalContext.redirect("error.xhtml");
        it.remove();
    }
    wrapped.handle();
}
```

When I catch a throwable of ViewExpiredException, I CAN get FacesMessages at @PostConstruct method of "ErrorBean"(which is attached to "error.xhtml"). But if any other type of throwable comes, I can NOT get any FacesMessages.
"ErrorBean" is a backing bean class with these 2 annotations:

```
@javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean
@javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
```

I'm assuming that its relevant to the "Life Cycle of JSF",
OR maybe because I have 2 beans attached to 1 page,
but I can't figure out why this is happening.

BTW, what I really want to do is output stacktrace on the same url (without http 3xx redirect), I tried something like below:

```
final ConfigurableNavigationHandler nav = (ConfigurableNavigationHandler)             
        facesContext.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
nav.performNavigation("error.xhtml");
```

but did not work out either (another bean for this page will show up and no faces messages),
so at this moment, I decide to go with redirect.

Please help me out! Thanks.

Comment: Try a `dispatch` instead of a `redirect`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496430/exception-handling-in-jsf-to-print-error-message-in-the-new-page

Comment: Uh! `@javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean`, `@javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped`?

Comment: @Xtreme Biker I tried it right now, but unfortunately it did not work. The ViewStateException went worse: setKeepMessages returns NullPointerException from inner classes, and there's tons of more logs flooding, so I have to stop TomEE...

Comment: Which version/implementation of JSF are you exactly using? There used to be some problems with the flash scope in earlier releases. I would go with [2.1.27 or 2.2.5 at least](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21277621/1199132).

Comment: @Tiny oh, yes indeed.. I started with javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped and javax.inject.Named but it did not work good with javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty 's, initiating orders. I hate these similar annotation.

Comment: @Xtreme Biker  -  I thought JSF 2.1 or 2.2 are not supported in TomEE1.7.3 (JavaEE6 based) . I want to use TomEE because I and my co-workers are familiar with Tomcat.

Comment: `@ManagedProperty` is a JSF artifact and is only supposed to be used in JSF managed beans. If it is a bean / EJB injection point, then use `@Inject` instead.

Comment: @Tiny - I use `@ManagedProperty` for injecting some common backing bean to another backing bean, both are `@javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped`, thanks for tips.

Comment: `@Inject` fits to that requirement.

Comment: @HirofumiOkino I'm not familiar with JavaEE environments (I am with servlet containers), but I think you could give it a try.

Comment: @Xtreme Biker - I checked my pom.xml and there are `org.glassfish#javax.faces#2.2.12`, `org.apache.myfaces.core#myfaces-api#2.1.8`, `org.apache.myfaces.core#myfaces-impl#2.1.8`, `org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk#tomahawk20#1.1.13`, I think I'm totally fxxcked up!! I didn't intend to put any of these to my project, so it came from some samples from TomEE or others.

Comment: @Tiny - ok, I replaced all `@ManagedProperty(value="#{commonBean}")` to `@javax.inject.Inject` and it's working fine thank you. And is `@javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean` bad in my case?

Comment: `@javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean` is a partially deprecated JSF artifact. Managed beans decorated with this annotation are governed by the JSF framework itself - not CDI which is another bean management framework. New projects should use CDI as a bean management framework avoiding JSF managed beans which are considered to be semi-deprecated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4347707/1391249

Comment: @Tiny ok, I replaced `@ManagedBean` back to `@Named` , except for one application scoped backing bean with `@javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean(eager=true)` and `@javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped`, I couldn't find `@Eager` annotation in OmniFaces1.12.1 ( which was also in my pom.xml). BTW, my first problem STILL EXISTS.... Do JSF beginners all have to deal with these dependencies, (semi-)deprecated, minor version stuffs? omg. I felt Spring or Struts was a lot easier to start with.

Comment: Equivalent to `eager=true` in application scoped JSF managed beans is not available in CDI. A stereotype `org.omnifaces.cdi.Startup` annotation can be used to get around the situation which is available, since OmniFaces 1.8 (You are already using a higher version and can thus make it available). Managing dependencies appropriately also affects other environments like Spring MVC, Struts etc, by the way. It is not related to JSF only.

Comment: Well, every article I see says about `@Eager` or @Startup under org.omnifaces.cdi package but I don't see this package in extracted files of http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/omnifaces/omnifaces/1.12.1/omnifaces-1.12.1.jar. So, I downgraded it to 1.8.3 which really has that package and annotation. I'm testing with it and no problem so far, but this time, I think I'm gonna ask to BalusC himself, about whether this feature is (semi-)Deprecated or not.... (I googled of course)

Comment: I really have to get my jobs done with JSF!! I chose JSF for my project by myself, because it looked **standardized** in modern JavaEE ( no Spring required). My question is still open, someone please help me out.

Comment: There was a description saying that OmniFaces 1.10 - 1.12 doesn't support optional CDI. Version 1.8 supports CDI v1.0 optionally, and over versions 1.2 support CDI v1.1. http://omnifaces.org/