# <o:form styleClass> not rendered when using MyFaces instead of Mojarra

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, myfaces, omnifaces

I've been developing a website with JSF2.0 TomEE 1.7.3.
In the last question I've asked :

[What are the recommended JSF dependencies with TomEE1.7.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34469630/what-are-the-recommended-jsf-dependencies-with-tomee1-7-x/34470114?noredirect=1#comment56682240_34470114)

I got advices and decided to migrate from GlassFish(Mojarra) Faces to myFaces, because myFaces is the standard JSF implementation of TomEE.

Then I realized that "OmniFaces v1.8.3 Form" is not rendering css class attribute with "style" nor "styleClass", if I use the default myFaces of TomEE. It worked fine with Mojarra, but now I get my HTML layout broken, and I have to fix it.

Reason I use "OmniFaces Form" is, I really want to use `includeRequestParams="true"` feature, and this works in BOTH Mojarra and myFaces.

My xhtml looks like bellow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
>
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="templates/common.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <o:form prependId="false" styleClass="form-horizontal" includeRequestParams="true">
                <!-- some inputText, labels, and buttons here -->
            </o:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

What I get in HTML is:

```
<form id="j_id_1k" name="j_id_1k" method="post" action="/foo.xhtml">
```

`class="form-horizontal"` is not rendered.

Am I missing something? are the xmlns wrong or deprecated?
or is it just a inconsistency between modules and I cannot do anything about it?
or is there something equivalent to `includeRequestParams` ?

I've tried something like this to attach css class to form tag with javascript (I know this is not a good approach):

```
(function() {
    var forms = document.forms;
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++){
        if (forms[i].id !== "headerForm"){
            forms[i].class = "form-horizontal";
        }
    }
})();
```

but it didn't fix the layout, maybe because css styles are attached to the objects INSIDE the form, not the form itself (I'm using css bootstrap).

Please help me out! thank you.

Comment: what does generated markup of the form say? Can a <div class="form-horizontal"> inside the form be acceptable?

Comment: @Mahendran Ayyarsamy Kandiar - Although I have to edit all my jsf pages, your answer (adding div inside) solved my problem, thanks! I'll leave my question for a while because I hope there is a straight answer.

Comment: BTW, the whole class attribute is dropped, other attribute are same as mojarra.

Comment: try with omnifaces-2.2. If issue still exists post it in https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues

Comment: How does the generated HTML output look like? Rightclick page in browser, *View Source*, do you see `<o:form>` still there, or do you see the HTML `<form>`? Symptoms suggest that it isn't recognized/compiled/rendered. You should then tell how exactly you installed OmniFaces.

Comment: @BalusC - I took a diff while searching for HTML structure difference - mojjara was : `<form id="j_idt54" name="j_idt54" method="post" action="/divisionAdd.xhtml" class="form-horizontal">`, myFaces was : `<form id="j_id_1k" name="j_id_1k" method="post" action="/divisionAdd.xhtml">`, my jsf tag was : `<o:form prependId="false" styleClass="form-horizontal" includeRequestParams="true">` .  So html form tag was rendered, not the class.

Comment: Ah, when you're using MyFaces instead of Mojarra, the `<o:form styleClass>` isn't rendered? Does this happen with `<h:form>` in MyFaces too?

Comment: Yes thats what I'm seeing. I got `<form id="j_id_1k" name="j_id_1k" method="post" action="/divisionAdd.xhtml" class="form-horizontal" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">` from myFaces tag `<h:form prependId="false" styleClass="form-horizontal">` It has class attribute rendered.

Comment: Right, I reproduced it too. I fixed it and posted an answer. Thanks for reporting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a mistake in `<o:form>`. It [initially](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/2.2/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/component/input/Form.java#L130) extended from [`UIForm`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIForm.html) class, but it doesn't have all non-common attributes definied. I [fixed](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/3f0a8f8fa039dff28a7a939348c57314b7a65885) it to extend from [`HtmlForm`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/html/HtmlForm.html) instead and now it works for me in MyFaces too. It's available in today's [2.3-SNAPSHOT](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/omnifaces/omnifaces/2.3-SNAPSHOT/).

Comment: Cool! thank you! Actually, I am using OmniFaces 1.8.3, and now trying hard to launch TomEE7.0.0-M1 so that I can use the latest OmniFaces SNAPSHOT which you fixed.....

Comment: @HirofumiOkino If you face issue with TomEE7 and OmniFaces 2.3 open a new question