# custom message fired from bean method

Tags: jsf

I have a command button on my page.

```html
<h:commandButton id="makeSearch" value="#{msg.makeWycena}">
     <f:ajax event="click" render="@all" listener="#{searchBean.makeSearch()}"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

`makeSearch()` method first checks value from database, and if this value is `null` it performs some logic. But when the value isn't `null`, then I would like to display an error message.

I thought about making `<h:outputtext rendered = {not null XXX}/>` and make special variable XXX for that reason, but I'm pretty much sure it can be done with plain `<h:message />` form, but can't find how.

My code looks like this :

```
else {
            FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            fc.addMessage(null , new FacesMessage("XXXXXXXX"));
            return null;
        }
```

I want the message XXXXXXXXX to be displayed in:

```
 <h:message for="makeSearch" globalOnly="true" style="color:red;margin:8px;"/>
```

next to command button I posted before. Right now it's rendered at the bottom of a page

---

After few changes my code looks like this right now :

```
<h:form id="detailsForm" prependId="false">
  <h:commandButton id="makeSearch" value="#{msg.makeWycena}">
  <f:ajax event="click" render="@all" listener="#{searchBean.makeSearch()}"/>
</h:commandButton>
<h:message for="makeSearch" id ="makeSearchError" style="color:red;margin:6px;left-margin:10px;"/>
```

and bean code :

```
else {FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("detailsForm:makeSearchError" ,
   new FacesMessage("XXXXXXXXXXXX")); }
```

but still. message don't render in h:message. I tried also detailForm:makeSeach and it didn't help either

Comment: Use `<h:messages>` for generated messages from server instead of the current `<h:message>`.

Comment: As in my particular page, I have only one message to display this approach is good, I will use this tip :) but still, would like to know how to do it in case I have few error messages to display in seperate message boxes in the future.

Comment: From [`FacesContext#addMessage`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#addMessage(java.lang.String, javax.faces.application.FacesMessage)) javadoc, the first parameter must be the client id. Since you're setting `null`, it means it doesn'tfind any component so it will go straight to `<h:messages>`. Refer to this Q/A for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/q/315804/1065197

Comment: FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("detailsForm:makeSearchError" , new FacesMessage("XXXXXXXXXXXXX"));
I tried that - message still was rendered outside the message box, so I changed message to messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `facesContext.addMessage(null, message)` ends up in a `<h:messages globalOnly="true">`, not in a `<h:message for="...">`. Note that `globalOnly="true"` is [not supported](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/message.html) on `<h:message>`.

So, replace

```
<h:message for="makeSearch" globalOnly="true" style="color:red;margin:8px;"/>
```

by

```
<h:messages globalOnly="true" style="color:red;margin:8px;"/>
```

---

As to your attempt with a fixed message client ID as per the comments, that's also invalid. You should specify the client ID of the component to which the message is associated by its `for` attribute, not the message component itself. So, you should not have used

```
facesContext.addMessage("detailsForm:makeSearchError", message);
```

but instead

```
facesContext.addMessage("detailsForm:makeSearch", message);
```

After all, that's unnecessary if you just fix the `<h:message>` to be a true `<h:messages>`.

Comment: As I wrote before - I tried both: detailsForm:makeSearch and makeSearchError - none of them worked, so I changed `<h:message>` to `<h:messages>`and it works. But I only need one error on this page, what if I need more than one?

Comment: Just add one more message by `addMessage()` the same way. The `<h:messages>` supports displaying multiple messages, on the contrary to `<h:message>` without the plural `s`.